# Get names of structs that implement an interface or inherit a struct

Tags: go

Is it possible to get a slice of strings that represent the names of all types that implement an interface or inherit from a specific struct in a specific package using reflection?

Comment: Go has an open-world model for this case. It is not possible to figure out who implements or embeds something: Go is allowed to throw out arbitrary unused code and that ability would either make the feature you want highly unpredictable (i.e. useless) or, if made predictable, would make it much more difficult for the Go compiler to throw out code.

Comment: Go 1.3 introduced [static analysis](http://golang.org/lib/godoc/analysis/help.html) for godoc, which will provide you with that information. But you won't be able to do that at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research on the `reflect` package's doc, I don't think it's possible. That's not the way reflection work in go: the interfaces mechanism not beeing declarative (but duck-typed instead), there is no such list of types.

That said, you may have more luck using the `ast` package to parse your project, get the list of types, and check wheter or not they implement an interface, then write some code to give you the said slice. That would add a step to compilation, but could work like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can't do this with `reflect`, since packages are kinda out of `reflect`'s scope.

You can do this the same way godoc's static analysis works. That is, using [`code.google.com/p/go.tools/go/types`](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.tools/go/types) to parse the package's source code and get the type info.

Answer (score 2):

The go oracle can do this. https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.tools/oracle

[Here is the relevant section of the user manual.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SLk36YRjjMgKqe490mSRzOPYEDe0Y_WQNRv-EiFYUyw/view#heading=h.15us5y9rxrbh)